# Передавать данные через WinSock серверу 10 раз в секунду

Tags: winsock, udp, сокет

**Пишу в Borland C++ Builder 6.** Есть клиент он отправляет серверу данные через UDP протокол с использованием технологии WinSock (клиент на ноуте, сервер на компе, оба они соединены Ethernet кабелем). Так вот в чем проблема раз передать данные, я могу или загнать в цикл чтобы они передавались постоянно тоже могу, **но вот чтоб они передавались 10 раз в секунду это для меня проблема**. Если есть какой-то метод или способ, рад буду его увидеть, заранее спасибо.

Вот кусок программы для которой это нужно сделать:

```
void Socket()
{
  char buf[1019];  // На самом деле buf пустой, но будем считать что там что-то есть 
  const int iReqWinsockVer = 2;
  WSADATA wsaData;

  if (WSAStartup(iReqWinsockVer,&wsaData)==0)
  {
    Form1->Memo1->Lines->Add("Инициализация библиотеки сокета(Ws2_32.dll) удалась");

    SOCKET s;
    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

    if (s == INVALID_SOCKET)
         Form1->Memo1->Lines->Add("При создании сокета возникла ошибка: " + WSAGetLastError());
    else
         Form1->Memo1->Lines->Add("Создание сокета было успешным!");

    sockaddr_in sockAddr;
    sockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    // Клиент:
    if(Form1->RadioButton2->Checked)
    {
       sockAddr.sin_port = htons(80);
       sockAddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr("169.254.128.135");

       // Здесь едет отправка данных и сразу выход, если убрать break, то будет передавать все время, но это не решает задачу  
       while(true)
       {
          // Отправляю данные
          sendto(s, buf, sizeof(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&sockAddr, sizeof(sockAddr));

          break;
       }
     }

    // Сервер:
    else if(Form1->RadioButton1->Checked)
    {
      sockAddr.sin_port = htons(80);
      sockAddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY;

      if (bind(s, (sockaddr*)(&sockAddr), sizeof(sockAddr))!=0)
         Form1->Memo1->Lines->Add("Связывание адреса с socket’ом не произошло");
      else
         Form1->Memo1->Lines->Add("Связывание адреса с socket’ом было успешным!");

      while(true)
      {
         sockaddr_in client_addr;
         int iSize = sizeof(client_addr);

         // Принимаю данные
         int ret = recvfrom(s, buf, sizeof(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &iSize);

         if (ret != 0)
         {
             Form1->Memo1->Lines->Add("Данные были полученны успешно!");
             break;
         }
         else
             Form1->Memo1->Lines->Add("При получении данных возникла ошибка");
        }
     }
     closesocket(s);

     if (WSACleanup() == 0)
          Form1->Memo1->Lines->Add("Освобождение ресурсов WinSock завершилось успехом");
     else
          Form1->Memo1->Lines->Add("Освобождение ресурсов WinSock не удалось");
   }
   else
      Form1->Memo1->Lines->Add("Инициализация библиотеки сокета(Ws2_32.dll) не удалась");
}
```

**P.S.** Не обращайте внимание на, то что этот код нечего полезного не делает. Я специально оставил самое нужное чтобы не тратить ваше время в разборке кода.

Comment: Sleep(100) - задержка в 100мс. В итоге данные будут слаться плюс-минус 10 раз в секунду.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов,  Sleep(100) я так понял нужно указать после sendto? И еще вопрос можно при получении сервером данных выводить время в мили секундах когда эти данные получены? А так вроде бы работает, но хотелось бы проверить правильно ли.

Comment: Можно и перед. Текущее время в мс с момента старта системы - GetTickCount(). Тоже плюс-минус лапоть.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, спасибо разобрался, но неудобное это GetTickCount(), выводит 1) 256918453 2) 256918562, не очень понятный результат, ну хоть так.

Comment: Разница 109мс как раз.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, Точно не сразу заметил, но все же есть ли что-то более понятное, например на сервере при получении данных в Memo добавляется строка "Данные были полученны успешно", а было  бы отлично если бы добавлялось что-то вроде - "Данные были полученны успешно - [15 минут 0 секунд 100 мили секунд]", знаете как это можно сделать?

Comment: GetSystemTime в помощь

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, это вроде бы, то что мне нужно, завтра протестирую, а то уже спать охота, спасибо большое за помощь